# Setting {"agent": false} on Node.js request module

Tags: node.js, http, request, agent

How can I set up the "agent" to false on the request module? Such as I can do on the http core[2] module?

[1] http://npmjs.org/request

[2] https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the option is hidden under the "pool" option. Only had to set up "pool":false. Thank you